# Elasticsearch - find goods tags that are a subset of matched user's tags

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
PUT /goods/goods/1
{
  "tag": ["apple","gold","4G"]
}

PUT /goods/goods/2
{
  "tag": ["apple","gold"]
}
```

There're goods with multiple tags, we also have users with multiple tags. We've trying to find the goods whose tags are a subset of user's tags.

eg:

```
user ["apple","gold","4G","fruit"] find goods 1 2
user ["apple","gold","4G"] find goods 1 2
user ["apple","gold"] find goods 2
user ["apple"] find nothing
```

Can Elasticsearch achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want to achieve is similar to the one described in [Finding Multiple Exact Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html).

It is not directly possible because of the last example you showed:

```
user ["apple"] find nothing
```

Elasticsearch would have to build a query `find me all goods that have only one tag 'apple'` and it is not possible to achieve directly with inverted index. It only stores the IDs of documents that contain that tag; this list will contain *all* the documents that contain that tag, irregardless if they also contain other tags. Please refer to this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html) for further details.

Although there is a work-around for [Exact Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_equals_exactly), in your case you want to retrieve documents in Elasticsearch that are subsets, i.e. contain any number of elements from the query but nothing more. Similarly to the exact match case, it cannot be done efficiently.

#### A scripted work-around

There is a possible work-around in case your data allows it. For instance, if your goods/users tag matrix is sparse (means they rarely share same tags) you may achieve your goal using [`bool should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query with a scripted filter:

```
POST goods/goods/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tag": {
                        "value": "apple"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tag": {
                        "value": "gold"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tag": {
                        "value": "4G"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "inline": "int k = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['tag'].length; ++i) { if (!params.user_tags.contains(doc['tag'][i])) { k +=1}   }   k == 0",
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "params": {
                    "user_tags": [
                      "apple",
                      "gold",
                      "4G"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query does the following (in a simplified way):

- `should` part: matches all the documents that contain *any* of the user tags;
- `script` part: filters out those that contain other tags

[`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) query allows to perform almost any query possible but it will most certainly not be as efficient as built-in `term` query (as it will not use the index but will rather perform a full-scan in worst case).

The idea is to use both `term` and `script` and unite them in an AND (`bool must` query) so the scripted part is applied only on the documents that are a potential match. (Notes about in which order the queries are applied in Elasticsearch can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order).)

#### Final note

As usual with Elasticsearch, to achieve best performance you might need to rearrange your data (like adding `tag_count` etc.). Try and find out what suits you best.

Hope that helps!